# Изменение страницы под Apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Установил apache на виртуальной машине ubuntu. Запустил localhost, теперь хочу изменить html страничку. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

В каталоге /var/www/ (по умолчанию) создайте index.html. В файле напишите свой код.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то этот файл создаёт апач при установке.

Comment: не ошыбаешся, вот только он не изменяется и не удаляется.
как зделать что бы в браузере писать не localhost а что нибудь другое пр rt.ru

Comment: Да, не ошибаетесь (при условии, что все устанавливалось и настраивалось по дефолту).

Comment: Ну, как это не меняется? Посмотрите права на запись, может изменять только создатель (рут) - по крайней мере так у меня (да и у всех должно быть то же).  
Что бы писать что-то другое, нужно прописать в hosts необходимые адреса для отклика (это действительно только для index.html как дефолтной страницы, если хотите создавать другие проекты, то нужно создать виртуальный хост).

Comment: Fairlooli, попробуйте его изменять с командой sudo. Например  
<pre><code>sudo nano /var/www/index.html</code></pre>  
Еще, как вариант можно изменить права файла командой chmod (не рекомендую).

Что-нибудь другое - это что?

Comment: Это не localhost, а к примеру rtor.ru.

Comment: Добавьте в /etc/hosts вот это:  

    127.0.0.1 rtor.ru www.rtop.ru

Comment: Для отклика дефолтной страницы, которую пытается править @Fairlooli, виртуальный хост не нужен.

Comment: С правами поосторожнее. А то я открыл доступ к одной мз папочек системных потом вся система и навернулась..... 

Comment: ой, чё ж вы так переживаете за права доступа на папку www-то?! там кроме ваших файлов ничего храниться не будет! Нет ничего страшного в CHMOD 777 на /var/www/